# php pdo display error prepare execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How I can display error with `PDO` with this specific prepare and execute:

```
try 
{

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ZZZZZZ, nomepostazimiele FROM postazimiele");
    $stmt->execute();

    while ($row_postazimiele = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
        $idnomepostazi = $row_postazimiele['idpostazi'];
        $nomepostazimiele = $row_postazimiele['nomepostazimiele'];

        echo "<option value=\"$nomepostazimiele\">$nomepostazimiele</option>";
    }
} 
catch (pdoException $e) 
{
    echo 'Attenzione: ' . $e->getMessage();
    $output = "Impossibile collegarsi al Data Base, Utente o Password errati"
            . "<br>" . "<br>" . "prego riprovare" . $e 
            . "<br>" . "<br>" . "<a href='miele.php'>Clicca QUI per ritornare alla pagina principale</a>";

    include 'errore.html.php';
    exit();
}
```

If I make error in a `SELECT` like up no error appears. why?

Can some one help me?

Comment: did u connect to database?

Comment: i connect to db.....

Answer (score -1):

You need to get the output of the execute, you want to show an error and not an exception.

```
if($stmt->execute()){
    echo "Error: ".$stmt->errorInfo();
}
```